# Prove if $m$ divides $n$, then $A_n \subseteq A_m$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[I've been pondering this question for a while and this is as close as I can get to it.. any help if you can solve it much appreciated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWIw3.png)

> Consider the family of sets, $A_k = \{a\in\mathbb Z; k\text{ divides }a\}$ where the indexing set is $S=\{k\in\mathbb N; k>0\}$. Prove the following:
>   a) If $m$ divides $n$, then $A_n\subseteq A_m$.
>   b) The function $f_{m,n}\colon A_m\times A_n\to A$ defined by $f(a,b)=ab$ is sujective.

a)
Suppose $x∈A_n$,
$n\mid x$,
$x=nc$

Suppose $x∈A_m$,
$m\mid n$,
$x=mj$

$x=nc$,
$x=(mj)c$,
$x=mjc$
→ $m\mid x$

$n\mid x$ and $m\mid x$ → $A_n⊆A_m$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site using MathJax.

Comment: Please replace the image of text by actual text and use proper formatting using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct but more coherently (and in MathJax markup):

If $m \mid n$, we know $n=km$ for some $k$.

If now $x \in An$ is arbitrary, we know $x=k'n$ for some $k'$ and then $x=k'(km)=(k'k)m$, which shows $x \in Am$. The inclusion has been shown.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your exercise is correct. You can write it in a more compact form by stating that:
$$ m|n \implies (a\in A_n \implies a = nx = mjx \implies a\in A_m) \implies A_n \subseteq A_m$$
The second part of the exercise asks just for surjectivity. So let $a \in A_{mn} $.
Then $a = mnx$, so that $f(m, nx) = a$. Note that since $f(mx, n) =a$, the function is not in general injective.